# #div_iv a:hover not working

Tags: css

This may seem stupid to ask, but I have done on many css coding

```
#div_iv a:hover
```

but for darn reason, it does not seem to work now, Googled with results such as

```
a.hover #div_iv
#div_iv:hover
```

What exactly is wrong.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a style using `#div_iv a:hover`, you will see the effect in a code like this:

```
<div id="div_iv">
  <a href="#">My Link</a>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work, check in your CSS file if you do not override this declaration, by specifying another link style declaration after this one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscore from your CSS.

```
div#iv a:hover
```

Then HTML:

```
<div id="iv"><a href="URL">sometext</a></div>
```

Comment: Your CSS code makes no sense like this, it says something like: select the hover pseudoclass of a link that is in an element `iv` that is a child of something with the ID `div`. 
To match your HTML, the CSS might look like: `div#iv a:hover` (select the hover pseudoclass of a link in the div element which has id 'iv').

Comment: You're right.. It's first thing in the morning.. Sorry. I'll ammend.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was **not** working is because the `id="div_iv"` **should have been in the href** tag

**darn me!!!**

Comment: I don't see how this can work with the CSS code that you posted in your question. If the a-element has the id `div_iv`, your CSS should look like `a#div_iv:hover`. Can you post the relevant CSS and HTML snippets of your code?

Comment: it would be
<a href="someurl.html" id="div_iv">some link</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make something in the entire DIV, then use following code:

```
#divID div:hover
```

or, if it does not work,

```
div#divID div:hover
```

Then, use this HTML code:

```
<div id="divID">Enter stuff and <a href="link.html">links</a> here.</div>
```